# VBA Name columns based on first row

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like to name "library" 's columns. Each column should have the name found in the 1st cell of that column. My code returns a 1004 error. What am I doing wrong ?

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Library")
    Dim x As Long, rng As Range
    For x = 1 To .UsedRange.Columns.Count
        Set rng = .Cells(2, x).Resize(.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1, 1)
       ThisWorkbook.Names.Add name:=.Cells(1, x).Value, RefersTo:=rng
        Set rng = Nothing
    Next
End With
```

Comment: What is the value of `.Cells(1, x).Value` when the error occurs?

Comment: @BigBen it's "Labels ". It seems that the error was coming from the space at the end of the name. Thanks

Comment: Are you recreating the functionality of a table (`ListObject`)?

Answer (score 0):

Answer: Do not include any special characters or spaces in the name that you want to give to your range.